# Why does Russian ruble conversion rate to USD remains constant at 1 to 0.01?

Tags: finance, international-economics, exchange-rates

I've been noticing that since Russian ruble started losing its value compared to other foreign currency, at some point it became at constant exchange rate of 1 RUB to 0.01 USD.

That is, every day no matter how much value the ruble keeps losing, at the beginning of a new trading day it bumps back to 0.01 USD:
[image]

This puts the ruble at an overall fixed value, since its previous day value is the same as new trading  day's value:

[image]

I assume Russia's central bank is taking measures to stabilize their currency's value, but is there a reason for this specific value? And how is it possible to achieve a fixed exchange rate? Buying your own county's currency with your own foreign currency reserves?

Comment: Almost certainly because the banks have largely given up on the Rouble… Test that by trying both buying and selling a few…

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Currently there are quite a few restrictions on US to Russia bank operations. The answer is that Google Finance [gets its data for the exchange rates](https://www.google.com/intl/en/googlefinance/disclaimer/) from a specific service, Morningstar, who are likely abiding by the sanctions and are no longer providing a quote.

If you check elsewhere, the price is different. E.g., at [xe.com](https://www.xe.com/currencycharts/?from=RUB&to=USD) they currently have

[image]

Comment: Even that graph does still have the same almost square-wave type pattern to it, though, which seems pretty odd.

Comment: The square wave pattern is probably related to the Russian central bank interventions and Russian business hours.